# What are implicit objects? What does it mean?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Whenever I study JSP and Servlets I come across word **implicit objects**, what does the term mean?

How they are called in my program without instantiating objects? Who instantiates implicit objects? Please elaborate.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Those are objects which are already been placed in the scope by the servlet container, so that it's accessible by EL (Expression Language), such as the [`PageContext`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html), [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29), [`HttpServletRequest#getHeader()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) and so on. Those are just for convenience so that you don't need to use old-fahioned *scriptlets* to grab them.

So instead of for example

```
<%= pageContext.getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval() %><br>
<%= request.getParameter("foo") %><br>
<%= request.getHeader("user-agent") %><br>
<%  for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) { // Watch out with NPE!
        if (cookie.getName().equals("foo")) {
            out.write(cookie.getValue());
        }
    }
%><br>
```

you can just do

```
${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}<br>
${param.foo}<br>
${header['user-agent']}<br>
${cookie.foo}<br>
```

You see that they follows the JavaBean conventions to be accessed (i.e. you can just invoke the getters the JavaBean way). You see that I used the brace notation `[]` to get the `user-agent`, that's because the `-` is a reserved character in EL, so `${header.user-agent}` isn't going to work, it would try to return the result of `request.getHeader("user") - pageContext.findAttribute("agent")` which is obviously not going to work.

For an overview of them all, check the chapter [**Implicit Objects**](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij) in the Java EE tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

> Implicit objects in JSP are the
>   objects that are created by the
>   container automatically and the
>   container makes them available to the
>   developers, the developer does not
>   need to create them explicitly. Since
>   these objects are created
>   automatically by the container and are
>   accessed using standard variables;
>   hence, they are called implicit
>   objects.
>
> The implicit objects are parsed by the
>   container and inserted into the
>   generated servlet code. They are
>   available only within the jspService
>   method and not in any declaration.
>   Implicit objects are used for
>   different purposes. Our own methods
>   (user defined methods) can't access
>   them as they are local to the service
>   method and are created at the
>   conversion time of a jsp into a
>   servlet. But we can pass them to our
>   own method if we wish to use them
>   locally in those functions.

Source: [roseindia.net](http://www.roseindia.net/help/java/o/jsp-implicit-objects.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Implicit objects are a set of Java objects that the JSP Container makes available to developers in each page. These objects may be accessed as built-in variables via scripting elements and can also be accessed programmatically by JavaBeans and Servlets.

For a detailed overview and use please see the page below.

http://www.gulland.com/courses/JavaServerPages/jsp_objects.jsp

Answer (score -1):

Implicit objects are created automatically and are ready for you to use. You cannot create other variables with same name with these objects.

Comment: Wrong. You can indeed make variables with the same name. However, you must define the scope. For example, a request scope.With that said, one shouldn’t create variables with an implicit object name for the sake of poor practice.

Answer (score -1):

JSP implicit objects are created by container while translating JSP page to Servlet source to help developers

Answer (score -1):

There are the nine type of implicit object, Implicit Objects are also called pre-defined variables.
1) request
2) response
3) application
4) session
5) page
6) pageContext
7) out
8) exception
9) config