# Validating numbers with Servlets and JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, validation

I'm working on a small Servlets & JSP application while learning web development.

I have a question regarding validations and passing values between jsp and servlets.

I have a "Beer" class, with a "rating" property (of type double).

The servlet that loads "edit.jsp" creates a Beer object and loads the current values from the DB.

```
BeerDAO beerdao = new BeerDAO();
Beer beer = beerdao.getBeer(id);            
request.setAttribute("beer", beer);
```

In the JSP, the object is displayed in the following manner:

```
...
<td class="left">Beer Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="${beer.name}"/></td>
...
<td class="left">Rating:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="rating" value="${beer.rating}"/></td>
...
```

Now, when I submit the form to the "update" servlet, each property is validated. In the case of the "rating" property, I convert it to a double.

Should I find an error in the validation (ie: letters, instead of numbers for the rating value), I want to go back to the form with the values that the user typed and an error message. Thing is, I need a Beer object in the request to be displayed in the form, but I can't pass the "rating" value to it, because it's not of the correct type. So right now I'm seeding the user back to a form with an empty rating.

I'm guessing I'm going at it wrong. So, what would be the proper way to validate numbers and get back to the edit form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most basic approach would be to have a `Map<String, String>` in the request scope where the key represents the field name and the value represents the validation error -if any.

```
BeerDAO beerdao = new BeerDAO();
Beer beer = beerdao.getBeer(id);            
request.setAttribute("beer", beer);
// ...

Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
request.setAttribute("messages", messages);
// ...

String rating = request.getParameter("rating");
if (rating == null) {
    messages.put("rating", "Please enter rating");
} else if (!rating.matches("\\d+")) {
    messages.put("rating", "Please enter numbers only");
} else {
    beer.setRating(Integer.valueOf(rating));
}

// ...
```

And then in the view

```
<input name="rating" value="${empty messages.rating ? beer.rating : param.rating}" />
<span class="error">${messages.rating}</span>
```

The conditional expression will show the beer rating when there is no message (and thus validation has passed) and otherwise the user-submitted value as request parameter.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, redisplaying user submitted data without XML-escaping it is prone to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html). I strongly suggest to install [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and use [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) function to escape the values.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>   
...
<input name="rating" value="${fn:escapeXml(empty messages.rating ? beer.rating : param.rating)}" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is pretty slick. I was not aware of param object.

Comment: You're welcome. For more about implicit objects in EL, see also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113286/what-are-implicit-objects-what-does-it-mean