# Detect blank HTML form input values

Tags: servlets

When I submit a HTML form with blank data it's still going into `else` block below:

```
    String n=request.getParameter("uname");
    String e=request.getParameter("mail");
    String p=request.getParameter("pwd");   

    if(n==null || e==null || p==null)
    {
        // ...
    } else
    {
       // ...
    }
```

How can I make sure that it enters the `if` block?

Answer (score 2):

Blank submitted input values do not arrive as `null`. Instead, they arrive as empty string. The `null` only means that the input value was not submitted at all (i.e. the input field was totally absent in the form).

If you're not interested in distinguishing the presence of a specific input field in the form, then add a `String#isEmpty()` check to the `if` block.

```
if (n == null || n.isEmpty() || e == null || e.isEmpty() || p == null || p.isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

You could even bake a custom utility method for this.

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String string) {
    return (string == null || string.isEmpty());
}
```

```
if (isEmpty(n) || isEmpty(e) || isEmpty(p)) {
    // ...
}
```

You can even go a refactoring step further with help of varargs.

```
public static boolean isOneEmpty(String... strings) {
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

```
if (isOneEmpty(n, e, p)) {
    // ...
}
```

If you would like to cover whitespace as well, then replace `string.isEmpty()` over all place by `string.trim().isEmpty()`.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [How to determine which form has been submited and to validate them in a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905475/how-to-determine-which-form-has-been-submited-and-to-validate-them-in-a-servlet/)
- [Validating numbers with Servlets and JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501606/validating-numbers-with-servlets-and-jsp/)

Comment: varargs version is really good , also the one liner null check.

Answer (score 1):

This is because **uname,mail,pwd** variables are not null instead these parameters contains empty strings.

i.e.
    uname="";
    mail="";
    pwd="";

when you check whether these parameters are null or not , it results into false and your else block executes and persist the record into database.

you can create a method to check empty string(s).

```
 public static boolean checkEmpty(String value){
    if(!(value==null))
       return value.isEmpty();

    return true;
 }
```

replace your if condition with this:

```
if(checkEmpty(n) || checkEmpty(e) || checkEmpty(p)){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String n=request.getParameter("uname");
if (n != null) n = n.trim();
if (n == null) n = "";

String e=request.getParameter("mail");
if(e != null) e = e.trim();
if(e == null) e = "";

String p=request.getParameter("pwd");   
if(p != null) p = p.trim();
if(p == null) p = "";

//
// only process if values for all three exist
//

if((n.length() < 1) || (e.length() < 1) || (p.length() < 1))
{
    // ...
} else
{
   // ...
}
```