# How to evaluate a scriptlet variable in EL?

Tags: jsp, scope, el, scriptlet

I was wondering if there was anyway of using JSP in `<c:if>` statement.

E.g.

```
<c:if test="${ param.variable1 == 'Add' <% JSP variable clause %>}">
```

So I want my JSP variable to checked against as well.

Any suggestions? I have tried ignorantly just sticking in the clause, obviously it did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So you want to evaluate a *scriptlet* variable in EL? Store it as a request attribute. The below example will make it available as `${foo}`.

```
<%
    String foo = "some";
    request.setAttribute("foo", foo);
%>

<c:if test="${param.variable1 == 'Add' && foo == 'some'}">
```

However, this makes no sense. You should [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) *scriptlets* altogether and use JSTL/EL to prepare this variable. So if you make the functional requirement more clear, e.g. "How do I do this (insert *scriptlet* code snippet) using JSTL/EL?", then we'll be able to suggest the right approach.

For example, you could use `<c:set>` to set a variable in EL scope.

```
<c:set var="foo" value="some" scope="request" />
```

Or if the JSP is forwarded by a servlet, then use `request.setAttribute()` over there right away.

```
String foo = "some";
request.setAttribute("foo", foo);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/your.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This will then be available as `${foo}` the same way.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Difference between <%= foo %> and ${ foo }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116289/difference-between-foo-and-foo/)
- [Use EL ${XY} directly in scriptlet <% XY %>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007689/use-el-xy-directly-in-scriptlet-xy)
- [What are implicit objects? What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113286/what-are-implicit-objects-what-does-it-mean/)
- [Generate an HTML Response in a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370960/generate-an-html-response-in-a-java-servlet/)

Comment: Just trying to experiment I tried *not* adding it to the request scope figuring it would be available in the page scope anyways. So I explicitly requested it from the page scope using in the EL: `pageScope.var`. Sure enough, it didn't work. Weirdly, when simply using `var` in the EL it *does* work without having to place the variable in the scriptlet code in request scope. What am I missing?

Comment: Why use request context? Simpler, more local, is `<% pageContext.setAttribute("var", "some"); %>`