# Use EL ${XY} directly in scriptlet <% XY %>

Tags: java, jsp, el, scriptlet

In my project I've to assign a variable every time the JSP is being opened.
I tried it with scriptlets `<% %>` in JSP and EL `${}` which gives the variable back.

But it seems not working.

```
 <% String korrekteAntwort=${frage.korrekteAntwort};%>
 <%session.setAttribute("korrekteAntwort", korrekteAntwort);%>
```

There is an error after `korrekteAntwort=${}`, Isn't it possible to assign directly an variable from EL in a scriptlet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're mixing *scriptlets* and EL and expecting that they run "in sync". That just won't work. [The one is an oldschool way of writing JSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) and [the other is a modern way of writing JSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). You should use the one or the other, not both.

Coming back to the concrete question, under the hoods, EL resolves variables by [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29). So just do exactly the same in *scriptlets*.

```
Frage frage = (Frage) pageContext.findAttribute("frage");
session.setAttribute("korrekteAntwort", frage.getKorrekteAntwort());
```

**However**, as said, this is an oldschool way of using JSPs and not necessarily the "best" way for [the functional requirement which you've had in mind, but didn't tell anything about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The modern JSP way would be using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:set>`:

```html
<c:set var="korrekteAntwort" value="${frage.korrekteAntwort}" scope="session" />
```

This will be available in session scope as `${korrekteAntwort}` from that line on, which is exactly what that line of *scriptlet* does.