# Calling a Javascript function without any event

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

This is a code written in a.jsp:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function chk(d,e)
    {
     var x = d.split('/')
     var y = e.split('/')
     var a = new Date(x[2],x[0],x[1])
     var b = new Date(y[2],y[0],y[1])
     var c = ( b - a )
     var p= c / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }
    </script>

    <% String b="2013/07/12";
       String c="2013/07/14";%>

   <script>
    var myVar=chk('$b','$c');
   </script>

   <body>
   <% String st="<script>document.writeln(myVar)</script>";
       out.println("value="+st); %>
   </body>
```

I want to get the number of days(i.e. 'p') between these 2 dates(i.e. 'b' and 'c') as the output. But the output I am getting is "value=NaN". What is wrong with this code? Please help.

Comment: You are splitting on `/` but sending in a date with `-`. Could that be it?

Comment: Is that production code or some weird twisted exercise?

Comment: @DustinLaine I really doubt that `$b` is the `b` variable in Java scriptlet. It should be at least `${b}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the function, add `return p;`.
Your function didn't returned anything that's why `undefined` was written on screen.

```
function chk(d,e)
{

 var x = d.split('/')
 var y = e.split('/')
 var a = new Date(x[2],x[0],x[1])
 var b = new Date(y[2],y[0],y[1])
 var c = ( b - a )
 var p= c / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
 return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was tricky to answer. First, looks like you want to pass the variables declared in scriptlet to your JavaScript using EL. To accomplish this, you should:

- Set the variable in scriptlet as pageContext attribute or request attribute as explained here: [How to evaluate a scriptlet variable in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5965812/1065197)
- Use JSTL `<c:out>` to send the variable from EL to your JavaScript function.
- Following GauravSharma's answer suggestion, add a `return p;` at the end of your JavaScript function.

Your code should look like this (at least works for me using Tomcat 7 and prints 2 in the navigator):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chk(d, e) {
        var x = d.split('/');
        var y = e.split('/');
        var a = new Date(x[0], x[1] - 1, x[2]);
        var b = new Date(y[0], y[1] - 1, y[2]);
        var c = (b - a);
        var p = c / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        return p;
    }
</script>
<%
    String b = "2013/07/12";
    String c = "2013/07/14";
    pageContext.setAttribute("b", b);
    pageContext.setAttribute("c", c);
%>

<script>
    var myVar = chk('<c:out value="${b}" />', '<c:out value="${c}" />');
</script>

<body>
    <%
        String st = "<script>document.writeln(myVar)</script>";
        out.println("value=" + st);
    %>
</body>
```

As said in my comment on your question, this looks like an exercise for practicing about scriptlets, EL, JSTL and JavaScript integration. **This kind of code is not meant to be used in a live production system NEVER**. Scriptlets usage is discouraged since long time. Refer to: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197). Also, show this to your teacher, professor or whoever is teaching you about Java web development.

Comment: Then could u please tell me a better way to perform the same task as above?

Answer (score -1):

Simply call write this

```
var myVar=chk('$b','$c');
```

on document ready.

Because `JSP` just written the `script` to `document`.Not executed yet.

Comment: I still don't understand what `'$b'` will be when calling `chk` method, won't be just plain `$b` text?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  May be it is `${b}`.

Comment: That's what I think, but not sure if its a typo or part of OP's problem (thus not providing an answer). If OP answer my question I made in the comments, I would dare to think on an answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza True words.I concentrated on the question straight away.

Comment: I have written the above code in document ready function, as you suggested. Now my output is"value= ".

Comment: I mean what jsp is printing