# Difference between <%= foo %> and ${ foo }

Tags: jsp, el, scriptlet

Coding in JSP for the first time, I need to render a variable's value to HTML. It looks like there are various ways to do this; what is the difference between these (given that I have a variable named `foo`)?

```
<%= foo %>
```

and

```
${ foo }
```

Comment: Please don't confuse JSTL with EL. I fixed the tags. To understand the difference, read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This, using an old fashioned output *scriptlet* which is [discouraged since a decade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/),

```
<%= foo %>
```

does basically the same as the following in a regular *scriptlet*:

```
<% out.println(foo); %>
```

which in turn does basically the same as the following in a normal Java servlet class  (you probably already know, JSPs ultimately get compiled and converted to a servlet class):

```
response.getWriter().println(foo);
```

where `foo` is thus declared as a local/instance variable. It thus prints the local/instance variable `foo` to the HTTP response at exactly the declared place.

---

This, using [expression language (EL)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), which is the recommended approach since JSP 2.0 in 2003,

```
${ foo }
```

does basically the same as the following in a regular *scriptlet*, with [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29):

```
<% 
    Object foo = pageContext.findAttribute("foo");
    if (foo != null) out.println(foo);
%>
```

which is in turn equivalent to:

```
<% 
    Object foo = pageContext.getAttribute("foo");
    if (foo == null) foo = request.getAttribute("foo");
    if (foo == null) foo = session.getAttribute("foo");
    if (foo == null) foo = application.getAttribute("foo");
    if (foo != null) out.println(foo);
%>
```

It thus prints the first non-null occurrence of the attribute in the page/request/session/application scope to the response at exactly the declared place. If there is none, then print nothing. Please note that it thus doesn't print a literal string of "null" when it's `null`, on the contrary to what *scriptlets* do.