# How to remove previous request parameter from URL query string

Tags: jsp, el

when i click on one category, it show the list of products of this category, the url will be:

```
http://localhost:9999/toyshop/home?category=Đồ%20chơi%20theo%20phim
```

but when I click on the next pagination page, the url will be

```
http://localhost:9999/toyshop/home?category{Đồ%20chơi%20theo%20phim}=Đồ%20chơi%20theo%20phim&page=2
```

This is my jsp code:

```
<c:remove var="param" scope="session" />
    <c:remove var="paramValue" scope="session" />
    <c:remove var="href" scope="session" />

    <c:remove var="param" scope="request" />
    <c:remove var="paramValue" scope="request" />
    <c:remove var="href" scope="request" />
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.productName}">
            <c:set var="servlet" value="search"/>
            <c:set var="param" value="product"/>
            <c:set var="paramValue" value="${sessionScope.productName}"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.categoryName}">
            <c:set var="servlet" value="home"/>
            <c:set var="param" value="category"/>
            <c:set var="paramValue" value="${sessionScope.categoryName}"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <!-- Handle the case where both are empty -->
            <c:set var="servlet" value="home"/>
            <c:set var="param" value=""/>
            <c:set var="paramValue" value=""/>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>

    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${empty paramValue}">
            <c:set var="href" value="${servlet}?"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="href" value="${servlet}?${param}=${paramValue}"/>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>


    <c:if test="${currentPaginationPage > 1}">
        <a href="${href}&page=${currentPaginationPage - 1}" class="pagination__item">
            <i class="pagination__icon fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </a>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${startPage > 1}">
        <div class="pagination__item pagination__item--none">...</div>
    </c:if>

    <c:forEach begin="${startPage}" end="${endPage}" var="page">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${page == currentPaginationPage}">
                <a href="${href}&page=${page}" class="pagination__item pagination__item--active">${page}</a>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <a href="${href}&page=${page}" class="pagination__item">${page}</a>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>

    <c:if test="${endPage < totalPaginationPage}">
        <div class="pagination__item pagination__item--none">...</div>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${currentPaginationPage < totalPaginationPage}">
        <a href="${href}&page=${currentPaginationPage + 1}" class="pagination__item">
            <i class="pagination__icon fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
    </c:if>
```

I'm expecting the url will be

```
http://localhost:9999/toyshop/home?category=Đồ%20chơi%20theo%20phim&page=2
```

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to paginate if you have both products and categories on the same page. Also there's no need to remove a scoped variable if you set it again.

Answer (score 0):

The `${param}` is a **reserved** variable in EL. It's basically an [implicit object](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/pages/3.1/jakarta-server-pages-spec-3.1#_Implicit_Objects) facade of `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`. You should not try to remove/overwrite it.

Use a different name than `${param}`. E.g. `${paramName}`.

```xml
<c:set var="paramName" value="category"/>
<c:set var="paramValue" value="${sessionScope.categoryName}"/>
```

```xml
<c:set var="href" value="${servlet}?${paramName}=${paramValue}"/>
```

#### See also:

- [What are implicit objects? What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113286/what-are-implicit-objects-what-does-it-mean/2113349#2113349)
- [How can I retain HTML form field values in JSP after submitting form to Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937624/how-can-i-retain-html-form-field-values-in-jsp-after-submitting-form-to-servlet)